# How do I embed facebook video in static FBML?

Tags: facebook, embed, fbml

I know it is common that we use the code below to embed a video from you, but how about the facebook itself??

```
<fb:swf
                swfbgcolor="000000" imgstyle="border-width:1px; border-color:white;"
                swfsrc='http://www.youtube.com/v/fZRSpjqzTH8&autoplay=1' 
                imgsrc='http://img.youtube.com/vi/fZRSpjqzTH8/2.jpg' width='259' height='204' />
```

for instance, I want to embed this video, http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=471202548012&ref=mf

I want it autoplay and find the thumbnail image like I can get it from youtube...

Is it possible for the video on facebook??

thanks,
Lau

Answer (score -1, accepted):

go to www.facebook.com/thefanpagefactory they can help you for sure. post it on the wall. Enjoy.

Comment: This answer is completely unhelpful. Answering that you should go ask the question somewhere else? *sigh*